# Can data source implementation be a view model?

Tags: ios, uitableview, mvvm, refactoring, viewmodel

I want to separate my `UITableViewDataSource`/`Delegate` implementation from my view controller. I'm using MVVM and I started to wonder if a data source implementation in a separate class can work as a view model. It would look something like this:
[image: Data source as view model]

If `UITableViewDataSource` protocol is not a good candidate for view model I can see two other ways to solve this: 1) with **a shared view model**:
[image]

or with 2) **separated view models**:
[image]

How to approach this to stay in the spirit of MVVM's separating *Presentation* from *Presentation Logic*?